# When to retrieve height for element with image in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagesloaded

In my web app, I want to display popup element which has `<img>` element in it. Image source is usually bigger than I need it, so it get's resized in css. And before I display it, I need to know it's `outerHeight`.

The popup looks something like this:

```
<div class="popupContainer">
  <div class="popupHeader">Header</div>
  <img class="popupImage" src="source" />
  <div class="popupMessage">message</div>
</div>
```

After I append it to another element, I'v tried retrieving it's height in two ways: simply `popup.outerHeight(true)` and using [`imagesLoaded`](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) library:

```
imagesLoaded(popup, function () {
  popup.outerHeight(true)
})
```

In most caes, both options return the same and expected result (like how tall the element actually is in browser). But there are times when option #1 returns height that is too small, because the image source hasn't been loaded yet, whereas option #2 returns height that is way too big, because the css hasn't been applied yet. (I think that those are the reasons). So I wanted to know, which is the best time to retrieve it's height? When the image will be loaded and element will be formatted correctly accoring to css.

Comment: Why don't you do the inverse: set the image's height and width based on your container size.

Comment: I am setting image width to a fixed size, but because they come in various aspect ratios, I can't set it's height without loosing the aspect ratio.

Comment: When is the image loaded? Along with the page or thru an event apart from load?

Comment: so you know the original width and original height, and the resized width? Shouldn't be too hard to get the resized height (tip: it's `(oH/oW)*rW`)

Answer (score 0):

You should do when the image will be loaded.